# Syntax of if statement and operator precedence

Tags: javascript, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

What exactly goes into an if statement's parens?

If I have:

```
if(setX(), x === 5)
```

Does that get interpreted as:

```
if((setX(), x) === 5) // which is the same as:
setX(); if(x === 5)
```

Or does it get interpreted as:

```
if((setX()), (x === 5))
```

(which is ultimately the same thing, but I'm still curious about the syntax.)

Comment: Why would you put a comma inside a condition? Or is it just a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things happening inside those parenthesis, in this order:

1. function call
2. equality comparison
3. comma operator

Code taken step by step:

```
// setup
function setX(){
  return 3;
}
x = 4;

// steps
if (setX(),x === 5)
// evaluate function call
if (3,4 === 5)
// evaluate equality comparison
if (3,false)
// evaluate comma operator
if (false)
// jump to the appropriate code branch
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 1):

Comma has the [least priority](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), so:

- `setX()` will be evaluated first
- `x === 5` will be evaluated second
- the `if` statement checks for `x === 5`

Answer (score 1):

The comma operator evaluates its two operands and returns the value of the right operand. Therefore your if statement will be the result of the x === 5 test performed after the setX() function.

Whether this is good programming style is however open to debate .... :-)